How to separate 2 variances from observed variance?
I have that I broke down to the following:
var(predicted_conc) = actual_conc*var1 + var2
Note that the random variable generators are independent, hence variance is added not standard deviation.
I run a simulation first to regenerate that information.
actual_conc <- c(0,3, 5, 10, 20, 30,50,80,90, 100, 150, 180)

predicted_conc <- c()
for(i in actual_conc){
   predicted_conc <- c(predicted_conc, i + rnorm(1000, mean =0, sd = (0.05*i)) + rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1))
}

As you can see, I had to separate random variable generation to scaled by concentration or just constant.
However, this relationship in not linear. I then calculate the variance, the non-linear relationship become very obvious, if I fitted either linear or quadratic regression, I get negative intercept, where the real constant variance is 0.01.
Despite I get close to the real value in this simulation if I used sd instead of var, and modeled sd~conc as the constant variance is small, I feel it should be more correct way to model that.
Ideas are appreciated.
Thanks!
EDIT
I guess this has to do with the variance as zero causes zero results! I have solid assumption of course that concentrations will not be negative at any point.

Please tell us what your statistical objectives are.  Why are you doing these calculations in the first place?

@whuber simply put, there are 2 independent sources of variability. I want to estimate what is the impact of each one of them in the future depending on the cumulative observed variance or standard deviation. Perhaps one solution is finding the variance at point 0, but it is slightly difficult to do.

Please tell us about your data and how you estimate the variability.

@whuber it is just repeated measures of known concentrations standards. Typically, repeated 10 times. The simulation is just hypothetical un-noisy data, where I replicated 1000 times. I calculate the standard deviation from those replicates then

Okay, but why are you trying to estimate a relationship between variance and concentration and why are you concerned that it might not be linear?


it is just repeated measures of known concentrations standards.

This is the crucial information here. I assume you are interested in how the precision of your analyzer depends on the concentration of the analyte. This means we can do regression analysis using an approach that also fits a variance model. This is implemented in the nlme package. We can use the variance model $\sigma^2(v) = a^2 + b^2 \cdot v^2$ if we fix the residual variance to 1. (With actual data you would test different variance models, see help("varClasses"), they usually don't require fixing the residual variance. You would also do this not with the predicted concentrations but with the actual signal of the analyzer, e.g., peak area or peak height.)
actual_conc <- c(0,3, 5, 10, 20, 30,50,80,90, 100, 150, 180)

predicted_conc <- c()
for(i in actual_conc){
  predicted_conc <- c(predicted_conc, i + rnorm(1000, mean =0, sd = (0.05*i)) + rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1))
}

predicted_conc <- matrix(predicted_conc, ncol = length(actual_conc))
matplot(actual_conc, t(predicted_conc), pch = 1, col = 1) 


library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(predicted_conc)
DT <- melt(DT, value.name = "predicted_conc")
DT[data.table(variable = paste0("V", seq_along(actual_conc)), actual_conc = actual_conc), 
   actual_conc := actual_conc,
   on = .(variable)]


library(nlme)
fit <- gls(predicted_conc ~ actual_conc, data = DT,
           weights = varConstProp (form = ~ actual_conc),
           control = list(sigma = 1))
summary(fit)

# Generalized least squares fit by REML
#   Model: predicted_conc ~ actual_conc 
#   Data: data.frame(DT) 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   42012.72 42042.29 -21002.36
# 
# Variance function:
#  Structure: Constant plus proportion of variance covariate
#  Formula: ~actual_conc 
#  Parameter estimates:
#       const        prop 
#  0.10007365 -0.04963053 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                  Value    Std.Error   t-value p-value
# (Intercept) -0.0019945 0.0027273500   -0.7313  0.4646
# actual_conc  0.9998167 0.0005128233 1949.6318  0.0000
# 
#  Correlation: 
#             (Intr)
# actual_conc -0.328
# 
# Standardized residuals:
#          Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
# -3.715184926 -0.681140888 -0.006216329  0.665166152  3.658746546 
# 
# Residual standard error: 1 
# Degrees of freedom: 12000 total; 11998 residual

As you can see the fitted coefficients of the variance model (0.10007365,  -0.04963053) are in excellent agreement with the known values from the simulation. Obviously, only the absolute values matter, because the coefficients get squared (and a standard deviation can't be negative).

wow! excellent insight. Thanks for your input!

I have a follow-up. Why did you choose to fix sigma to 1?

Read help("varConstProp").

Thanks! so the coefficients' results are for standard deviation no variance, right?

Yes..............
